# Owl Carousel inside div display:none not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

I have an owl carousel inside a div, the div is hidden with display:none; and I change it toggling via jquery.

HTML/PHP structure:

```
<em class="otherdemoicon"></em>

<div class="otherdemos">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="has-carousel" data-items="4" data-loop="true" data-dots="true" data-auto="false" data-navs="false">
            <?php foreach ($list as $item) : $images = json_decode($item->images); ?>
                <div class="item text-center">
                    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" itemprop="url">
                        <img src="<?php echo $images->image_intro ?>" alt="client" />
                        <?php echo $item->title; ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.otherdemos {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: #111;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid #222;
    display: none;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
```

The trigger div script:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.otherdemoicon').click(function () {
            $('.otherdemos').toggle();
        });
})(jQuery);
```

Jquery script for owl carousel:

```
(function ($) {
    //Carousel
    var $has_carousel = $('.has-carousel');
    if ($has_carousel.length > 0) {
        $has_carousel.each(function () {
            var $self = $(this);
            var c_item = ($self.data('items')) ? $self.data('items') : 4;
            var c_item_t = (c_item >= 3) ? 3 : c_item;
            var c_item_m = (c_item_t >= 2) ? 2 : c_item_t;
            var c_delay = ($self.data('delay')) ? $self.data('delay') : 6000;
            var c_auto = ($self.data('auto')) ? true : false;
            var c_loop = ($self.data('loop')) ? true : false;
            var c_dots = ($self.data('dots')) ? true : false;
            var c_navs = ($self.data('navs')) ? true : false;
            var c_ctr = ($self.data('center')) ? true : false;
            var c_mgn = ($self.data('margin')) ? $self.data('margin') : 30;
            var c_animateOut = ($self.data('animateOut')) ? $self.data('animateOut') : 'fadeOut';
            $self.owlCarousel({
                navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"],
                items: c_item, loop: c_loop, nav: c_navs, dots: c_dots, margin: c_mgn, center: c_ctr, animateOut: c_animateOut,
                autoplay: c_auto, autoplayTimeout: c_delay, autoplaySpeed: 300,
                responsive: {0: {items: 1}, 480: {items: c_item_m}, 768: {items: c_item_t}, 1170: {items: c_item}}
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The problem is that the display:none causes owl to don't resize items correctly inside the div when triggered.

I don't want to use opacity: 0/1 and height: 0/auto for some reasons so I tryed to refresh the carousel when triggered but no way:

```
$('.otherdemoicon').click(function () {
    $('.otherdemos').toggle();
    $(".has-carousel").trigger("refresh.owl.carousel");
});
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I checked your code https://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/yux2ndak/ Everything works for me... after I added required css class `owl-carousel` to your `.has-carousel` element

Comment: For me problem is in some external plugin. It is hard to debug for me. Try to turn-off JS plugins from this website one by one..

Comment: I just load jQuery v1.12.4, owl.carousel.js, and script.js that contains the script for toogling and for owl; I don't know what's wrong :(